# Проверка массива на дубликаты при вводе в поле

Tags: jquery, массивы

Подскажите, есть массив `itemSource`, мне нужно при вводе в поле `Name_Page` проверять массив на дубликаты и выводить сообщение, если они появляются:

```js
var itemSource = [];
itemSource = ['test', 'test1'];

$("#Name_Page").keyup(function(){
 //?????????????????????????
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="Name_Page" name="Name_Page" title="Название страницы">
<div class="error"></div>
```

Comment: Вам нужно проверить совпадает ли значение инпута с элементом массива?

Comment: Именно, извиняюсь если вопрос поставил криво, с мобильника писал ((

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если не нужна поддержка IE можно воспользоваться  [Array.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```js
var itemSource = [];
itemSource = ['test', 'test1'];

$("#Name_Page").keyup(function() {
   console.log(itemSource.includes($("#Name_Page").val()));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="Name_Page" name="Name_Page" title="Название страницы">
<div class="error"></div>
```

Comment: Поддержка IE обязательна, спасибо за пример.

Comment: по ссылке есть полифил, можете добавить в свой код

Comment: спасибо, нужно чаще в мануал заглядывать...спасибо ))